# Installing a Griffon plugin in zip format from private remote url

Tags: plugins, griffon

Somehow I cannot find and answer to this in griffon documentation nor googling...

I have created a griffon plugin. It gets packaged as usual with:

`griffon package-plugin`

Then I can install it locally in my application specifying path to the zip file resulting from packaging:

`griffon install-plugin /path-to-plugin/plugin-name.zip`

I can even upload it to a remote url and install it from there:

`griffon install-plugin address-of-my-site/plugin-name.zip`

**How can I make installing of this plugin from my url an automatic step during building/running of a griffon application, which uses it?**

I work on the application with another developer and don't want to force him to install the plugin manually every time when something changes. It should be downloaded from my site automatically. But I don't want to release the plugin to the griffon official repository either - it's pretty experimental stuff still.

There is a line in application.properties, which tells griffon, that the plugin is needed:

`plugins.plugin-name=0.3`

But it cannot be installed from griffon central repository, like all the other plugins, because it's not there, obviously.

I looked into documentation of "griffon.project.dependency.resolution" section in BuildConfig.groovy, but I can't find anything useful for my purposes there.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you seek is found in sections 12.1 and 12.2 of the guide. The first section describes an example of a plugin being pushed to a local repository. The second section describes the types of repositories supported by Griffon.

Plugins that are available from a plugin repository that can be queried by the build system (i.e, the repository is configured) are instantly available to be installed using the short notation you want.

There's always a local repository configured by Griffon: griffon-local. Pushing releases to it will make them instantly available to `install-plugin`, `list-plugins`, `plugin-info`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, aalmiray. I've seen the sections of the guide you mentioned, but I kinda hoped there is a faster solution, than setting up an internal Maven repository for build artifacts. It's just one file. SVN is out of question, since we use git as VCS. And the mentioned plugin should be shared only in deployed state (zip) anyway. All right, Maven it is then.

Comment: Hmm it's not a maven repository, it's a Griffon local repository. The default local repository is always enabled so you  don't need to set it up. However if you need to share the release with other teammates then what you have to do is run a remote repository, which is done by downloading https://github.com/griffon/griffon-artifact-portal and running it with Grails.